# 音声即時再生のためのコード.prepareToPlay( )をコードに入れたところ、コンパイルエラーが出てしまいました。

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, ios8

初めまして。
swiftを勉強し始めて1週間の初心者です。（プログラミングの経験もかなり浅いです。）

先ほど「世界一受けたいiPhoneアプリ開発の授業」という本を元にコードの写経をしていたところ、コンパイルエラーが出てしまいました。
1〜2時間ほど考えてみたり、コードを打ち直してみたり、Xcodeを再起動してみたり、色々試しましたがエラーは消えず…。という状態です。

エラーでは

> Value of Optional type "AVAudioPlayer" not unwrapped; did you mean to
>   use "!"or"?"?

エラーを治すための指示は

> Fix-It Insert "!"

と書いてありますが、!を挿入してもエラーが出たままです。逆に?を挿入したらエラーは無くなるんですが、これってどういうことが原因なのでしょうか？

コードは下記になります。（冒頭のcopyrightなどは省略させていただきます。**で囲まれたところにエラーが出ます。）

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation //AVFoundationをインポートする

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player:AVAudioPlayer?  //音声を制御するための変数

    //BGM再生メソッド
    func play(soundName:String){
    //String型の引数からサウンドを読み込む
        let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(soundName)

    //読み込んだファイルにパスをつける
        let url:NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath)
    //playerに読み込んだmp3ファイルへのパスを設定する
        player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
        player?.numberOfLoops = -1 //BGMを無限にループさせる
        **player.prepareToPlay() //音声を即時再生させる**
        player?.play() //音を再生させる
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //playファイルの呼び出し、引数はファイル名
        play("BMG.mp3")
    }

    @IBAction func wineTapped(sender:UIButton){

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

ちなみに、これはコードの問題じゃないのかもしれませんが、上記コードの**で囲まれた部分を修正してエラーがない状態にしても、シミュレーターを立ち上げた際にうまく立ち上がってくれません。

なお、Xcodeのバージョンは6.3.1（6D1002）です。

何か解決策があれば教えて下さい。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問への回答ではないのですが、参考にされている書籍のサポートページにてXcode6.3(Swift1.2)向けの対応情報が公開されていました。(http://gihyo.jp/book/2015/978-4-7741-7295-8/support) 書籍はXcode6.2(Swift1.1)向けに書かれているとのことで、他のサンプルでも同様の修正が必要となりますので、一度こちらを確認された方が良いかもしれません。Swiftはまだまだ発展途上の言語なので、今後も仕様変更があるかもしれないので、Xcodeがバージョンアップした際にはAppleの開発者サイトをチェックしてみるといいですよ。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

エラーを出さないようにする訂正のしかたは、

```
player?.prepareToPlay()
```

が正解です。

Swiftにおけるオプショナル（Optional）型について、きっちり勉強なさって、理解するようにしてください。Appleが開発言語をObjective-CからSwiftに変更した理由の、半分以上がこのOptional型にあるといっても、過言ではないので。
Optional型は、nilが代入されることを許容する変数の型をいいます。裏返しに表現すると、一般の変数（非Optional型）は、nilを許容しません。代入しようとした値がnilだったら、プログラムエラーになり、アプリ全体が落ちます。
変数がnilを許容しないとはどういうことかというと、プログラム内のバグが潜む場所を、減らしていこうという意図です。iOSのフレームワークを、今後使っていくとわかってきますが、処理に失敗すると、返り値をnilとするメソッドが多数あります。そういうメソッドの後、返り値がnilかそうでないかで、条件分岐したプログラムを書いていれば、堅牢なプログラムに近づくんでしょうが、現実には、「ここでnilなんて、返ってこないでしょ？」ですましているプログラムが多数あります。そういう局面で、ちゃんと条件分岐するよう、プログラマに促す意味が、Optional型にあります。
なので、Optional型を生かすようなプログラムにするなら、こういうコードになるでしょう。

```
func play(soundName:String){
    let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(soundName)
    let url:NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath)
    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
    // Optional Chainingを使う。
    if let thePlayer = player {
        thePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        thePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        thePlayer.play()
    }
}
```

`if let thePlayer = player {}`は、ただの条件文ではなく、**Optional Binding**という特殊な構文です。Optional型の変数`player`の値が、nilでなければ、Unwrapした値を、非Optional型の変数`thePlayer`に代入します。（`else {}`を追加すると、`player`がnilだったときの処理を行えます。）